# connecting 2 routers wireless

Tags: networking, wireless-bridge

we have two independent networks in 2 offices...one in LG and one in 16th floor:

```
USERS----LINKSYS RV082 router-----+ISP+DHCP enabled ==on 16th floor ++(INTERNET)
```

and same on LG(lower ground)

```
USERS----LINKSYS RV082 router-----+ISP+DHCP enabled ==Lower Ground ++(INTERNET)
```

we want to connect both routers but the DHCP of the other router would be disabled and each router would still have its own ISP. could you help us what to do....we're thinking of the transparent bridging but don't know yet what to do.. we want the routers to be physically connected like this:

```
USERS----LINKSYS RV082 router-----+ISP+DHCP enabled ==on 16th floor ++(INTERNET)         
              #
              #
              #
              #
USERS----LINKSYS RV082 router-----+ISP-DHCP disbled ==Lower Ground ++(INTERNET)
```

where the `####` is the connection/cable but what would it be? Like doing transparent bridging? Or using switch on 16th floor and a cat6 down to LG?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking - are you looking to connect the two networks behind the routers?

Comment: oh sorry..i mean how to connect both routers(on different floor/office) in transparent bridging..that they'll share on same DHCP but each router will have its own ISP

Comment: @user159903 you might want to add why you are clinging to the idea to have two routers in your setup and what you want to achieve with the interconnection between the 16th floor and the LG.

Answer (score 2):

While there would be not much of a problem to interconnect the two routers' "LAN" segments and set them up in a single IP subnet, your clients are only going to use one of them - the one entered as the "default gateway" in their configuration.

If your aim is to "bundle" the two internet links for either resiliency or higher bandwidth, you would need a different kind of setup where a *single* router acts as a default gateway and has two uplinks where it can distribute traffic to accordingly. Your [Linksys/Cisco RV082](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9926/index.html) indeed *do* have two WAN uplinks and the ability to spread out outbound connections among them. Your setup would look somewhat like

```
 ISP1       ISP2
   \         /
    \       /
+- WAN1   WAN2 -+
+               +
+    Linksys    +
+  RV082 router +
+               +
+----- LAN -----+
       / \
      /   \
     /     \
  Lower    16th
 ground    floor
```

Comment: I gave a +1 because I love ASCII art.

Answer (score 0):

> *in transparent bridging..that they'll share on same DHCP but each router will have its own ISP*

This is what you call "advanced routing". You'd have a single network with two uplinks. Someone's got to decide which uplink gets the traffic. If you've got two ISPs, best to not put them on a single shared network; separate out the networks so each one is independent. Or perhaps re-think what you're trying to accomplish.